# turtlebot 1.0 calibration

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just updated to the most recent debs:

ii  ros-electric-turtlebot                     0.9.0-s1329169192~lucid
ii  ros-electric-turtlebot-apps                0.9.0-s1329172196~lucid
ii  ros-electric-turtlebot-robot               1.0.0-s1329209176~lucid

Now when I:

roslaunch turtlebot_calibration calibrate.launch

I get a neverending stream of errors:

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1329273192.794075] bad callback: <bound method ScanToAngle.scan_cb of <**main**.ScanToAngle instance at 0x2918200>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/topics.py", line 581, in _invoke_callback
cb(msg)
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_calibration/src/turtlebot_calibration/scan_to_angle.py", line 74, in scan_cb
angle=atan2((-sum_x*sum_y+num*sum_xy)/(num*sum_xx-sum_x*sum_x), 1)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1329273192.865006] bad callback: <bound method ScanToAngle.scan_cb of <**main**.ScanToAngle instance at 0x2918200>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/topics.py", line 581, in _invoke_callback
cb(msg)
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_calibration/src/turtlebot_calibration/scan_to_angle.py", line 74, in scan_cb
angle=atan2((-sum_x*sum_y+num*sum_xy)/(num*sum_xx-sum_x*sum_x), 1)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27647/turtlebot-1.0-calibration/) by [Peter Henry](https://answers.ros.org/users/1510/peter-henry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the robot in front of a wall? Does the wall appear in the laser scan? I just pushed a small change that will hide the error message (it will be a day or so before this makes it into the debians), but the bottom line is that your robot cannot see a wall in front of it.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1